# when importing web3 in python getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

I am trying to execute the "import web3" statement in python console and getting the following error.

EDIT: I am using Python 3.9.0a1 and pip 21.3.1.

I have tried doing it both in VSCode terminal and windows command prompt.

```
>>> import web3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from web3.main import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\main.py", line 87, in <module>
    from web3.manager import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 47, in <module>
    from web3.providers import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .rpc import (  # noqa: F401,
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 21, in <module>
    from web3._utils.request import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 6, in <module>
    from aiohttp import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 48, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Protocol
  File "C:\Users\f1cmpica-1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py", line 2142, in <module>
    def TypeAlias(self, parameters):
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned no version numbers.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I installed these from conda-forge, with interpreter 3.9.7 on MacOS 12.0.1:

- typing-extensions         4.0.1
- web3                      5.26.0

And then `import web3` works Just Fine.

Comment: Added, I hope this makes it more understandable.

Comment: Please do not use alpha python 3.9.0a1; there's no good reason for that. Please use a more modern version, or revert to some stable release such as 3.8.12.